# Sum of squares of even integers from 1 to x using python function

Tags: python

```
Def summation(x):
    
    sum=0
    for i in range(1, x+1):
       sum= sum+(i*i)
    return sum

x=int(input("Enter no: ")

summation(x)

print("The summation of squares of even numbers from 1 to", x, "is", summation(x))
```

how to get the sum of squares of even number from 1 to x? I only know how to get the sum of squares from 1 to x.

I tried adding an if statement but i keep getting the wrong sum of squares as follows:

```
Def summation(x):
   sum=0 

   for i in range(1, x+1):
      If (x%2==0): 
         sum= sum+(i*i)
      return sum

x=int(input("Enter no: ")

summation(x)

print("The summation of squares of even numbers from 1 to", x, "is", summation(x))
```

Comment: Can you show us the if statement you tried, and what output you got?

Comment: `s = sum(x*x for x in range(1,11))` (assuming x = 10)

Comment: Def summation(x):
    sum=0
        for i in range(1, x+1):
             If (x%2==0):
                 sum= sum+(i*i)
             return sum
                   
x=int(input("Enter no: ")

summation(x)

print("The summation of squares of even numbers from 1 to", x, "is", summation(x))

Comment: @day6 please edit it into your question if you can, also check out Timur's answer as it should answer your question

Comment: No need for a loop :) `print((2 * n * (n + 1) * (2 * n + 1)) / 3)`

Comment: @balderman OP asks for even numbers so the range is `range(2, 11, 2)`

Comment: @zaid i cant edit it, I'm only using my phone and im not yet familiar with this website im sorry. I really appreciate your comments

Comment: No worries, I will update that for you.

Comment: @ZaidAlShattle Make sure you lowercase the `def` as well!

Comment: On another note, the reason your existing code didnt work is because you are checking the x in `if (x%2==0)`, you should check the i as in `if (i%2 == 0)`

Comment: @MartesBerkeley that's a good point, but I cannot make a single character edit which makes it realy hard for me to edit it again haha.

Answer (score 3):

You can try this approach using list comprehension with the built-in [`sum`](https://docs.python.org/library/functions.html#sum) function. Unlike other solutions, you can skip the even number check by adding a [`step=2`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/stdtypes.html#range) parameter at the end.

```py
def summation(x):
    result = sum([i**2 for i in range(2, x + 1, 2)])
    return result
```

Comment: I like the usage of range to get even numbers, didn't even know it worked like that until I just checked. but I would also recommend you add a bit of explanation to the answer.

Answer (score 2):

First of all, I would try to stay away from sum, as it is a pre-defined function in Python.

Then you could use the following code:

```
def summation(x):
    s = 0
    for i in range(1,x+1):
      if i%2 == 0:    
        s += i**2
    return s
```

the % operand returns the rest of the division, therefore any even number will have 0 rest and all odd numbers will have rest of 1.
I also used the += operator:

```
s += 1
```

is equivalent to

```
s = s + 1
```

Lastly, the ** operator is used for raise something to the power of something else i.e.

```
3**2 == 9
```

Comment: Are you sure about the i% without a number after? I think you mean to write i%2?

Comment: Oops, I guess typos are easier when typing here, sorry!

Comment: No worries mate :)

Answer (score 1):

Use [list comprehension](https://docs.python.org/tutorial/datastructures.html#list-comprehensions)
with a conditional, and [`sum`](https://docs.python.org/library/functions.html#sum), like so:

```
x = 5
print(sum([i**2 for i in range(x) if not i%2]))
```

Prints: `20`

If you need to include `x` in the list, simply change `x` to `x+1`:

```
print(sum([i**2 for i in range(x+1) if not i%2]))
```

**[EDIT]**
(thanks to *DeepSpace*)
Use a [generator expression](https://docs.python.org/howto/functional.html#generator-expressions-and-list-comprehensions) instead of a list comprehension for memory efficiency, as it avoids building and holding the list in memory. Also, use `range` with a step `2` for speed to avoid iterating over elements which we do not need (the odd numbers). So a better answer looks like this:

```
print(sum(i**2 for i in range(0, x + 1, 2)))
```

Comment: Instead of checking for the parity, I'd use `range` with a step argument. It is (arguably) more readable **and** performs better (since we don't iterate over numbers we don't need to begin with, and `%` is quite an expensive operation we'd want to avoid if we can). Also, we obviously can start at `2` and not `1`: `range(2, x + 1, 2)`

Comment: And while we are at it, we might as well not create the list and give `sum` a generator: `print(sum(i ** 2 for i in range(2, x + 1, 2)))`

Comment: @DeepSpace Thank you for suggesting using `range` with a step and a generator! I updated my answer.